# Java Math.pow rounded to integer returns the same number several times

Tags: java, math, exponent

I'm trying to make clicker game and I want robot price to multiply like in cookie clicker game. I tried to use cookie clicker's price calculating formula (http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Building).

```
if (cookies >= robotPrice) {

                cookies -= robotPrice;
                cps ++;
                //Here is the algorithm
                robotPrice = 100 * (int)Math.pow(1.15, cps);

                System.out.println("robotPrice set to " + robotPrice);

            }
```

But when I run the program, i get following output:

```
robotPrice set to 100
robotPrice set to 100
robotPrice set to 100
robotPrice set to 100
robotPrice set to 200
robotPrice set to 200
robotPrice set to 200
robotPrice set to 300
robotPrice set to 300
```

etc.
Please help.

Comment: This "(int)Math.pow(1.15, cps)" giving you one, that's why

Comment: You probably wanted `(int) (100 * Math.pow(1.15, cps))`.

Comment: Somehow cps value is between 0 to 4, debug your code

Comment: Show the code having loop. This snippet has only `If` condition. I am pretty sure that `cps` is being reset to `1` here otherwise there is no error in the code. Even type casting is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people pointed out in the comments, the problem arises in this line of code `robotPrice = 100 * (int)Math.pow(1.15, cps);`

You are taking 1.15, raising it to the power cps, then cutting off all decimal places. Which would only give you a whole number and then multiplying by 100.
You want to multiply it by 100 before you remove all the decimals.
`robotPrice = (int)(100 * Math.pow(1.15, cps));`